# How to power admin template with firebase without nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, angularfire

I have been searching for days now on a way to power my angularJs admin template with Firebase without having to install node.js on my server since it is not supported in the first place.

Someone please advice and help me with some example.

Comment: There's a few examples on https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html how come you haven't found it in your *"searching for days"*?

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate. I should have said a working firebase-angular authentication project for use in my project. This means a user should first log in to access information in the admin dashboard